Is it an issue to set a file path that does not include a directory with System.IO.File.Move
I am new to C# and was testing the renaming of files with System.IO.File.Move to see how it functioned.
My second parameter I did not include a full path to the item I wanted to modify, which I see now is necessary to do.
Here's the code I ran:
var fileToRename = "C:\\Coding\\Testing\\zesty.txt";

System.IO.File.Move(fileToRename, "Updated.txt");


After running the snippet above in VS Code the following error message displayed in the console: "exited with error code -532462766", and the file is not visible in the folder it was previously in.
I don't care about the file as it was just for testing, but I was wondering what happened to the file that I just renamed and did not even specify a directory for? Is the data still in the system somewhere and retrievable, or is the file more or less 'destroyed' now and will be overwritten whenever something else is saved to whatever piece of memory it is/was present in? Is it a problem at all? Thanks!

That path "without a folder" is a relative path. It will be combined with the process' working directory to get the final destination path. What that working directory is depends on how you launched the process. This is true of anything that deals with paths.

When File.Move() fails with an exception then it won't move anything and thus won't modify the file on disk.

Is the data still in the system somewhere and retrievable - it's possible to ask explorer to search an entire hard disk when looking for a file, btw; just launch your search from c:\ ..

The file is moved to the path specified in the second parameter. However, if the drive (e.g., C:/) is not explicitly declared, the path is treated as relative. So, the file is moved to a location relative to where the executable is running, typically within the directory of the .sln file at /bin/Debug/net8.0/.
